# Common Groovy Scripts at the Project Level in ReadyAPI

Tags: groovy, soapui, ready-api, common-code

Looking for a way to have common groovy scripts at a project level.

I see that one can have common scripts [across ReadyAPI as a whole](https://support.smartbear.com/readyapi/docs/testing/scripts/library.html), but I'm looking for something on the project level.

There's lots of shared groovy code so we'd prefer having it in all in one centralized place. This is also so if someone imports the project they'd have everything they need without having to import additional libraries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The script library can be set per project, in project properties.

[citation](https://support.smartbear.com/readyapi/docs/projects/properties.html)

Comment: It was this easy, can't believe I missed it.Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can also have dynamic path in Script Library property as below. If you put your library folder in your project folder. Then you can commit and push your library so that all your teammates can access to it.

${projectDir}/...

Comment: Yup, that's what we ended up doing. Makes source control a cake walk